# Start with Docker

Tags: docker

Very first steps with Docker on Debian:

```
docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

What is wrong?

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: Nope, Debian 10

Comment: Did you “Docker login” to the hub?

Comment: No i did not login

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Windows Docker, you'll need to set the Docker Engine Experimental to true.

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [
    "https://hqmn6wry.mirror.aliyuncs.com"
  ],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true
}
```

Comment: Debian 10, not Windows

Comment: 1. You can try adding it to the /etc/docker-daemon. json file, or create it manually if it doesn't exist.   2. systemctl daemon-reload    3. systemctl restart docker